# Purpose of batch channel in tensorflow model on forward pass of 1 input

Tags: tensorflow, keras, computer-vision, training-data

So far I have trained a couple different models in TensorFlow (with Keras) and I see that getting the batch_size right seems to be important not just for speed of training but also the resultant accuracy of the model.

What confuses me is a case where a model has an actual batch channel as the first dimension on the input (and output as well). If my batch size is 32 but I'm always inputting 1 data at run-time then where does the batch channel apply?  How could I utilize the vast majority of it if I'm inherently only using 1/batch_size amount of it in forward pass?

If you are curious the model I am researching, it is this one:

https://github.com/pierluigiferrari/ssd_keras/blob/master/models/keras_ssd300.py
see:

## Output shape of `predictions`: (batch, n_boxes_total, n_classes + 4 + 8)

```
predictions = Concatenate(axis=2, name='predictions')([mbox_conf_softmax, mbox_loc, mbox_priorbox])
```

The tensors had run through numerous other layers that had constants and such pretrained with [batch_size] as well.  To me it just seems like inputs at various batch index would have to yield different results.  Maybe I just need something incredibly obvious pointed out to me.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that after training you must recompile the model with a batch size of 1, then transfer the weights from the training model to the new model for evaluation. The alternative is performing 'batch_size' count of predictions at once (which of course is not always feasible per application).  If there are alternatives (or if I read wrong) please feel free to add an answer.